# Automatically assign Elastic IP from a pool of IPs to auto scalling instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am trying my hand at autoscalling and all is well except that I need all of my instances to be assigned an elastic ip (this is for my payment gateway which needs to know all IPs that we are using.)

Im happy to add say 8 elastic ips to my account but what I need is a facility to auto assign one of these to the instance as it boots up and then release it as it switches off.

I guess I need a startup script but this is beyond my knowledge of AWS (so far I do everything through the web console).

Any samples/help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your gateway is deployed in the same Amazon account as your servers, you might want to look at a [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/autoscalingsubnets.html) solution where you can control the instances' *private* IPs using masks.

If that is not an option, you will need to write a script, which you should add to the Launch Configuration's [User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

In this script you can use [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html) to find which IP Addresses are available using [`describe-addresses`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html), and use one of them to associate to your newly created instance using [`associate-address`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html).

Comment: Your right, I need the user data script as its the PUBLIC IP I need control over.  Ideally I want a sample script to get me going as I havent dont any CLI stuff (with or without AWS!).

Comment: @Raj - you simply need to write a `bash` script. (you just have to make sure that the `aws-cli` is properly installed on the AMI you are launching, and that the instance has the proper credentials, preferably using `IAM Roles`)

Comment: How about on Windows instances, which is what I am working with?

Comment: @Raj, addmitedly, I don't have experience with windows machines on EC2, but this may be a good starting point: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html